# Как создать List-массив на C++?

Tags: c#, c++

я бы хотел спросить, возможно ли на C++ реализовать list-массив так, как это работает на C#? Это должен быть безразмерный массив с возможность заменять любую из его составляющих частей, добавлять новые элементы, проверять наличие указанной составляющей. Проще говоря, мне нужен приблизительно следующий код, но не на C#, а на C++:

```
using static System.Console;
OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

List<string> tryc = new List<string>();
for (int timer = 1; timer <= 3; timer++)
{
    Write("Введите слово - ");
    tryc.Add(ReadLine());
}
if (tryc.Contains("Me"))
{
    string toString = "";
    foreach (string now in tryc)
    {
        Write($"{now} ");
        toString += now;
    }
    WriteLine($"\nВторое слово - {tryc[1]}");
    int countOfI = toString.Count(x => x == 'I');
    WriteLine($"Количество букв 'I' во введенных словах: {countOfI}");
    string replaced = toString.Replace("Me", "He");
    WriteLine($"\n\n{replaced}\n\n");
}
```

[image: Желаемый вывод]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но в с++ есть std::vector и std::list. я не знаю, что Вам лучше подойдет, но по умолчанию обычно берут вектор

```
List<string> tryc = new List<string>();
```

это

```
std::vector<std::string> tryc;
```

добавление

```
tryc.Add(...);
```

это

```
tryc.push_back(...);
```

Поиск

```
tryc.Contains(...)
```

это

```
if (std::find(tryc.begin(), tryc.end(), ...) != tryc.end())
```

ну и подключить хедеры

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```